# How to plot a bar plot with specific values of my dataset?

Tags: r

I'm stuck with a R case study.
I need to plot a graph using specific values in my dataset. I have trouble finding the right code. How should I write it?

The dataset is:

```
data <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScPoEcon/ScPoEconometrics/master/inst/datasets/airline-safety.csv")
```

The question is:

Propose a vizualization showing the evolution of the number of fatal accidents between the two periods

I want to plot a bar plot with my two periods of time in x axis, number of accidents in y axis.

Here is how far I managed to code:

```
graph_1 <- summarise(group_by(data, type, period), sum_1 =sum(value) )
ggplot((data = graph_1),
aes(x=period, y=type))
geom_bar()
```

It outputs a graph with:
the two periods on the x axis
accidents type on the y axis

However, it doesn't use the number of accidents per accident type.

I would expect to have:

- x axis: period 1985_1999,
- y axis: N° of accidents with a bar of 122 for fatal accidents.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: maybe `geom_bar(stat="identity")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Which is what `geom_col()` is for, just to make it a bit easier.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried both using `geom_bar(stat="identity")`  and `geom_col()` . The plot is similar to the initial situation. Thank you very much to both of you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a *fill* to aesthetic. Usually, you want to include the numeric value in `y` column and categorical values like `type` in `fill` or `color`.

```
# SUMMARY DATA
graph_1
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   type [3]
#   type            period    sum_1
#   <fct>           <fct>     <int>
# 1 fatal_accidents 1985_1999   122
# 2 fatal_accidents 2000_2014    37
# 3 fatalities      1985_1999  6295
# 4 fatalities      2000_2014  3109
# 5 incidents       1985_1999   402
# 6 incidents       2000_2014   231

# PLOT OUTPUT
ggplot((data = graph_1), aes(x=period, y=sum_1, fill=type)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge")  # OR geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: Bar Plot Output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If I understand the code well: you added a layer called "fill" to arrange the plot with the categories of "type". What is `geom_col(position="dodge"` doing? Thanks again!

Comment: Great to hear! Technically, ggplot layers are added with `+` operator. I simply changed aesthetics mapped in `aes()` and *dodge* is to set bars besides each other as default is stacked bars: `position="stack"`.